# Substitute an element X in a list with 0.5*X

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with 33600 Elements and I have to replace every element bigger than 6000 with its half. I "practiced" with a smaller list and tried the following:

```
List1 = {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000};
ListNew = {};

Do[
 {
  Numb = Take[List1, n ;; n],
  NumbNew = 0.5 Numb,
  
  ConditionalExpression[Numb > 9000,

   ListNew = Append[ListNew, NumbNew]],

  ListNew = Append[ListNew, Numb]
  }
 ,
 {n, 1, Length[List1]}]
```

I want ListNew to look like this:

> {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 5000}

But what I get is this:

> {5000., 1000, 5000., 2000, 5000., 3000, 5000., 4000, 5000., 5000, 
> 5000., 6000, 5000., 7000, 5000., 8000, 5000., 9000, 5000., 10000}

I tried to use `If` too, but neither did it work

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `ListNew = If[# > 6000, #/2, #] & /@ List1` or long form: `fn = Function[{x}, If[x > 6000, x/2, x]]; ListNew = Map[fn, List1]`

Comment: Also your question is a bit inconsistent. You ask for > 6000 at the top paragraph, and yet in your code you've written `> 9000` and your expected answer looks like you've used `> 9000` too. As for your coding style, avoid procedural `Do` loops and `Append`, and instead prefer functional constructs like `Map` wherever possible except where the procedural approach is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Big Thanks to all who have helped! You guys are awesome

Answer (score 6):

```
(# + # UnitStep[6000 - #])/2 & @ List1
```

> ```
> {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000}
> ```

Comment: For long lists this should be fast.

Answer (score 4):

A method close to the one the OP was going for:

```
ListNew = Table[
   If[TrueQ[n > 6000], 0.5 * n, n],
   {n, List1}
]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lst1 = {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000};

lst1 /. x_ /; x > 6000 -> x/2

(*  {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: I recommend using `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`) for this.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit It would be interesting if you give reasons. It seems that even without RuleDelayed it works. So, what one gains with it?

Comment: `x` is a very commonly used variable and if it has a value, `Rule` will not do the right thing here because `x` will evaluate on the r.h.s. of `Rule`. Try evaluating `x = 1` before doing the replacement with `Rule` to see what I mean. Generally, any replacement rule that uses pattern matching with variables should be done with `RuleDelayed` unless you have something very specific in mind.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit OK, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
listnew = List1 (Boole[Thread[List1 <= 6000]] + 1/2 Boole[Thread[List1 > 6000]] )

{1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000}
```

The first Boole is 1 when the list numbers are smaller than 6000 and the second Boole is 1/2... this then is multiplied by the values of List1.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in functions [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) and [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) are good for this kind of thing. Simply, define a piecewise function that implement your condition and map over your list to get a new one. Like so:

```
With[{max = 9000}, f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x ≤ max}, {x/2, x > max}}]]
new = f /@ {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000}
```

> {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 5000}

This more concise form will work as well, but is a little less readable:

```
With[{max = 9000}, f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x ≤ max}}, x/2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst//#.DiagonalMatrix[Clip[UnitStep[#-6000],{1,0},{1,1/2}]]&
```

> {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000}

​